# mail is not sending to my site to godaddy workspace

Tags: php, email

```
        <?php
        if($_REQUEST['submit']=='SEND'){

        $to= 'info@mysatoristudio.com,aespino@brainwaveadvertising.com,sales@mpsinfoservices.com,tamali@mpsinfoservices.com,tathagata@mpsinfoservices.com,tamali@mysatoristudio.com';

        /* $to='ananya@mpsinfoservices.com';*/
        $mailmessage = '
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Contact Us</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        </td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">You have Successfully registerd for "Satori studio"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Your Name : '.$_REQUEST['name'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Your mail ID : '.$_REQUEST['email'].'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>
        ';
        $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        /*  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"."\r\n";*/
        $headers .= "From: Satori studio <info@mysatoristudio.com>" . "\r\n";
        $subject = 'Registration for "Satori studio"';

        mail($to,$subject,$mailmessage,$headers);
        header("Location:index.php?msg=seccess");
        }
        ?>
```

The mail is sending from my site to every mail server like google,yahoo etc...but not in godaddy workspace mail id...is this a coding problem???or others...Please suggest...

Comment: Why do you try to send such message as html message? This makes things complex, error prone and opens huge security threads to each receiver. Use a normal plain text message instead, it serves your purpose much better.

Comment: About your question: how should _we_ know if you have an encoding problem here? We don't know the encoding of your pages and requests, you do. We don't know the contents of your $_REQUEST elements, you do. We don't know the final content of the message sent out, you do.

Comment: inside $mailmessage='';if i write simple text,then also msg is not sending only "info@mysatoristudio.com" mail id created in workspace of godaddy...in others mail id it works fine....

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by adding

```
ini_set('SMTP', "relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
ini_set('smtp_port', "25");
```

before calling the mail function, as follows :

```
public function sendEmail( $text , $subject , $name , $sender_email , $destination )
{
    $headers="From:$name <$sender_email>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $sender_email\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Date: " . date("r") . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $sender_email\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Message-ID: " . date("r") . $name ."\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Importance: High\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-MXMail-Priority: High\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP Mailer 1.0\r\n"; 

    ini_set('SMTP', "relay-hosting.secureserver.net");
    ini_set('smtp_port', "25");

    mail( $destination , $subject , $text , $headers ); 

    return true;
}
```

I also noticed that the mail only sends when using `charset=iso-8859-1`,

I think there might be something missing in the server configuration on godaddy workspace where it is not allowing utf-8 charset through mail. I think the support might help in this case if you really need the utf-8 charset.